# Powershell rename a file with wildcard characters

Tags: powershell, rename

how can I rename a file like this?

```
Cf.EL#131.csv.[daily_report+cf.com]
```

where .com] is the extension.

when I try this:

```
 $file='Cf.EL#131.csv.[daily_report+cf.com]'
 Rename-Item $file pippo.txt
```

Comment: What part do you want to use for wildcards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Rename-Item` cmdlet doesn't have a `LiteralPath` parameter which is what you need in this case since the file path has square brackets in it which are used for character classes per the POSIX standard. So as a work around use `Move-Item`:

```
Move-Item -LiteralPath $file -Destination pippo.txt
```